# Can't get child tag value through key to parent tag

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I am trying to alter/fix an existing xslt1.0 stylesheet, but there is something I don't understand why it won't work.

This is a part of the XML:

```
l: part of the xml
<Survey>
<SurveyHeader name="230222-CODE-TEST_1"/>
<Equipment>
<GPSReceiverDetails id="GPS_1" manufacturer="Leica Geosystems AG" model=" " serialNumber=" "/>
</Equipment>
<GPSSetup id="GPSSetupID_4" GPSReceiverDetailsID="GPS_1" antennaHeight="1.544000" stationName="GPS0001">
<GPSPosition pntRef="GPS0001" wgsLatitude="53.201424895062324" wgsLongitude="6.564586909979438" wgsHeight="42.733122">
<TargetPoint name="GPS0001" pntRef="GPS0001" >580062.951336 233674.586902 1.958197</TargetPoint>
<GPSQCInfoLevel2 covarianceXX="0.0000556906" covarianceXY="-0.0000044136" covarianceXZ="0.0000055377" covarianceYY="0.0000384521" covarianceYZ="0.0000021151" covarianceZZ="0.0000702572" RMS="1.000000" startTime="1361092385" stopTime="1361092385"/>
</GPSPosition>
</GPSSetup>
</Survey>

h: part of the xml
<Survey name="230222-CODE-TEST_1" SurveyDuration="P0Y0M0DT0H4M4S">
<GPSSetup uniqueID="GPSSetupID_4">
<GPSPosition targetPntRef="GPS0001" tiltCompensated="true" verticalOffset="0.000000">
<GPSQuality HDOP="0.600000" GDOP="1.878829" PDOP="1.252996" VDOP="1.100000" TDOP="1.400000"/>
<SatelliteInfo GPSSatTracked="9" GPSSatUsed="9" GALILEOSatTracked="4" GALILEOSatUsed="4" GLONASSSatTracked="6" GLONASSSatUsed="5" BEIDOUSatTracked="12" BEIDOUSatUsed="12"/>
<RTKInfo referenceRef="RTCM-Ref 0028" networkSolution="true" networkType="i-MAX" dataFormat="RTCM v3" ipAddress="nl.nrtk.eu" port="7801" mountpoint="MSM_iMAX" insideRTKNetwork="Inside" GPUID="" numRefStationUsed="1" numRTKPositionUsed="0"/>
<GPSPositionVelocity velocityX="0.017137" velocityY="0.001990" velocityZ="-0.010346" linearVelocityUnit="linearUnitPerSecond">
<VelocityQuality Qxx="0.00073671" Qxy="-0.00014277" Qxz="0.00014533" Qyy="0.00039546" Qyz="-0.00000568" Qzz="0.00262066" MeanError="1.00000000"/>
</GPSPositionVelocity>
<TiltInfo tilt="2.09289226" tiltQuality="0.20604831" maxTilt="2.09289172" maxTiltQuality="0.20604831" tiltDirection="292.82119353" tiltDirectionQuality="6.73585423" antennaHeading="126.49655262" antennaHeadingQuality="1.56022984">
<AttitudeQuaternion w="0.545783971615954" x="0.014694157165700" y="-0.007365463010343" z="-0.837764697290921">
<QuaternionQuality Qxx="0.0000105379" Qxy="0.0000002941" Qxz="-0.0000101108" Qyy="0.0000108098" Qyz="0.0000066687" Qzz="0.0008271720" MeanError="63.6619772368"/>
</AttitudeQuaternion>
<AngularVelocity velocityX="-3.1438191155" velocityY="1.5740678692" velocityZ="-1.4080006143" AngularVelocityType="angularUnitPerSecond">
<VelocityQuality Qxx="0.0000001490" Qxy="0.0000002552" Qxz="-0.0000000169" Qyy="0.0000005309" Qyz="0.0000000154" Qzz="0.0000003482" MeanError="63.6619772368"/>
</AngularVelocity>
<LeverArm deltaNorth="0.001000" deltaEast="0.000280" deltaUp="-1.643910"/>
</TiltInfo>
</GPSPosition>
</GPSSetup>
</Survey>
```

In the xslt template I have the following key and variable:

```
<xsl:key name="KeyGPSPositionH" match="h:GPSPosition" use="@targetPntRef" />

<xsl:template match="l:GPSPosition">

  <xsl:variable name="gpsSetupH" select="key('KeyGPSPositionH',@pntRef)" />
```

If I then use:
`<xsl:value-of select="$gpsSetupH/h:GPSQuality/@HDOP" />` it returns the value of HDOP from the xml
or:
`<xsl:value-of select="$gpsSetupH/h:SatelliteInfo/@GPSSatTracked" />` it returns the value of GPSSatTracked from the xml

But if I change it to:
`<xsl:value-of select="$gpsSetupH/h:TiltInfo/@tiltQuality" />` or `<xsl:value-of select="$gpsSetupH/@verticalOffset" />` it returns nothing despite it having the same parent tag as the other two.

I tried to change it to `<xsl:value-of select="$gpsSetupH/h:GPSPosition/h:TiltInfo/@tiltQuality" />` and change the key so it starts in the Survey tag `<xsl:key name="KeySurveyH" match="h:Survey" use="h:GPSSetup/h:GPSPosition/@targetPntRef" />` but both options don't work.

Comment: If you want anyone to tell where your XPath or XSLT fails on a sample document then make sure examples/samples are minimal but complete. With no sample values in the XML and with no context for e.g. `<xsl:variable name="gpsSetupH" select="key('KeyGPSPositionH',@pntRef)" />` we certainly can't tell which nodes you try to select or why some selection fails.

Comment: Is there any attribute named `pntRef` in the sample XML or what does `@pntRef` refer to?

Comment: I've added some more information. The pntRef refers to l:GPSPosition/@pntRef

Comment: The `<xsl:key name="KeyGPSPositionH" match="h:GPSPosition" use="@targetPntRef" />` certainly can't occur inside of `<xsl:template match="l:GPSPosition">` so that is far from a minimal but complete sample.

Comment: Please post a [mcve], not snippets taken out of context.

Comment: Sorry, that key is called in the main body of stylesheet, not in the template.

Answer (score 0):

When I use XSLT 1.0 with XslCompiledTransform and try to morph your snippets into minimal, formatted, complete samples I get the XML as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <Survey>
      <SurveyHeader name="230222-CODE-TEST_1"/>
      <Equipment>
         <GPSReceiverDetails id="GPS_1"
                             manufacturer="Leica Geosystems AG"
                             model=" "
                             serialNumber=" "/>
      </Equipment>
      <GPSSetup id="GPSSetupID_4"
                GPSReceiverDetailsID="GPS_1"
                antennaHeight="1.544000"
                stationName="GPS0001">
         <GPSPosition pntRef="GPS0001"
                      wgsLatitude="53.201424895062324"
                      wgsLongitude="6.564586909979438"
                      wgsHeight="42.733122">
            <TargetPoint name="GPS0001" pntRef="GPS0001">580062.951336 233674.586902 1.958197</TargetPoint>
            <GPSQCInfoLevel2 covarianceXX="0.0000556906"
                             covarianceXY="-0.0000044136"
                             covarianceXZ="0.0000055377"
                             covarianceYY="0.0000384521"
                             covarianceYZ="0.0000021151"
                             covarianceZZ="0.0000702572"
                             RMS="1.000000"
                             startTime="1361092385"
                             stopTime="1361092385"/>
         </GPSPosition>
      </GPSSetup>
   </Survey>
   <Survey name="230222-CODE-TEST_1" SurveyDuration="P0Y0M0DT0H4M4S">
      <GPSSetup uniqueID="GPSSetupID_4">
         <GPSPosition targetPntRef="GPS0001"
                      tiltCompensated="true"
                      verticalOffset="0.000000">
            <GPSQuality HDOP="0.600000"
                        GDOP="1.878829"
                        PDOP="1.252996"
                        VDOP="1.100000"
                        TDOP="1.400000"/>
            <SatelliteInfo GPSSatTracked="9"
                           GPSSatUsed="9"
                           GALILEOSatTracked="4"
                           GALILEOSatUsed="4"
                           GLONASSSatTracked="6"
                           GLONASSSatUsed="5"
                           BEIDOUSatTracked="12"
                           BEIDOUSatUsed="12"/>
            <RTKInfo referenceRef="RTCM-Ref 0028"
                     networkSolution="true"
                     networkType="i-MAX"
                     dataFormat="RTCM v3"
                     ipAddress="nl.nrtk.eu"
                     port="7801"
                     mountpoint="MSM_iMAX"
                     insideRTKNetwork="Inside"
                     GPUID=""
                     numRefStationUsed="1"
                     numRTKPositionUsed="0"/>
            <GPSPositionVelocity velocityX="0.017137"
                                 velocityY="0.001990"
                                 velocityZ="-0.010346"
                                 linearVelocityUnit="linearUnitPerSecond">
               <VelocityQuality Qxx="0.00073671"
                                Qxy="-0.00014277"
                                Qxz="0.00014533"
                                Qyy="0.00039546"
                                Qyz="-0.00000568"
                                Qzz="0.00262066"
                                MeanError="1.00000000"/>
            </GPSPositionVelocity>
            <TiltInfo tilt="2.09289226"
                      tiltQuality="0.20604831"
                      maxTilt="2.09289172"
                      maxTiltQuality="0.20604831"
                      tiltDirection="292.82119353"
                      tiltDirectionQuality="6.73585423"
                      antennaHeading="126.49655262"
                      antennaHeadingQuality="1.56022984">
               <AttitudeQuaternion w="0.545783971615954"
                                   x="0.014694157165700"
                                   y="-0.007365463010343"
                                   z="-0.837764697290921">
                  <QuaternionQuality Qxx="0.0000105379"
                                     Qxy="0.0000002941"
                                     Qxz="-0.0000101108"
                                     Qyy="0.0000108098"
                                     Qyz="0.0000066687"
                                     Qzz="0.0008271720"
                                     MeanError="63.6619772368"/>
               </AttitudeQuaternion>
               <AngularVelocity velocityX="-3.1438191155"
                                velocityY="1.5740678692"
                                velocityZ="-1.4080006143"
                                AngularVelocityType="angularUnitPerSecond">
                  <VelocityQuality Qxx="0.0000001490"
                                   Qxy="0.0000002552"
                                   Qxz="-0.0000000169"
                                   Qyy="0.0000005309"
                                   Qyz="0.0000000154"
                                   Qzz="0.0000003482"
                                   MeanError="63.6619772368"/>
               </AngularVelocity>
               <LeverArm deltaNorth="0.001000" deltaEast="0.000280" deltaUp="-1.643910"/>
            </TiltInfo>
         </GPSPosition>
      </GPSSetup>
   </Survey>
</root>
```

the XSLT as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
  
  <xsl:key name="KeyGPSPositionH" match="GPSPosition" use="@targetPntRef" />

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()" name="identity">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="GPSPosition[@pntRef]">
    <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
    <xsl:variable name="gpsSetupH" select="key('KeyGPSPositionH',@pntRef)" />
    <xsl:comment>
      <xsl:text>tiltQuality: </xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="$gpsSetupH/TiltInfo/@tiltQuality" />
      <xsl:text>; verticalOffset: </xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="$gpsSetupH/@verticalOffset"/>
    </xsl:comment>

  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and the result as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<root>
   <Survey>
      <SurveyHeader name="230222-CODE-TEST_1" />
      <Equipment>
         <GPSReceiverDetails id="GPS_1" manufacturer="Leica Geosystems AG" model=" " serialNumber=" " />
      </Equipment>
      <GPSSetup id="GPSSetupID_4" GPSReceiverDetailsID="GPS_1" antennaHeight="1.544000" stationName="GPS0001">
         <GPSPosition pntRef="GPS0001" wgsLatitude="53.201424895062324" wgsLongitude="6.564586909979438" wgsHeight="42.733122">
            <TargetPoint name="GPS0001" pntRef="GPS0001">580062.951336 233674.586902 1.958197</TargetPoint>
            <GPSQCInfoLevel2 covarianceXX="0.0000556906" covarianceXY="-0.0000044136" covarianceXZ="0.0000055377" covarianceYY="0.0000384521" covarianceYZ="0.0000021151" covarianceZZ="0.0000702572" RMS="1.000000" startTime="1361092385" stopTime="1361092385" />
         </GPSPosition><!--tiltQuality: 0.20604831; verticalOffset: 0.000000-->
      </GPSSetup>
   </Survey>
   <Survey name="230222-CODE-TEST_1" SurveyDuration="P0Y0M0DT0H4M4S">
      <GPSSetup uniqueID="GPSSetupID_4">
         <GPSPosition targetPntRef="GPS0001" tiltCompensated="true" verticalOffset="0.000000">
            <GPSQuality HDOP="0.600000" GDOP="1.878829" PDOP="1.252996" VDOP="1.100000" TDOP="1.400000" />
            <SatelliteInfo GPSSatTracked="9" GPSSatUsed="9" GALILEOSatTracked="4" GALILEOSatUsed="4" GLONASSSatTracked="6" GLONASSSatUsed="5" BEIDOUSatTracked="12" BEIDOUSatUsed="12" />
            <RTKInfo referenceRef="RTCM-Ref 0028" networkSolution="true" networkType="i-MAX" dataFormat="RTCM v3" ipAddress="nl.nrtk.eu" port="7801" mountpoint="MSM_iMAX" insideRTKNetwork="Inside" GPUID="" numRefStationUsed="1" numRTKPositionUsed="0" />
            <GPSPositionVelocity velocityX="0.017137" velocityY="0.001990" velocityZ="-0.010346" linearVelocityUnit="linearUnitPerSecond">
               <VelocityQuality Qxx="0.00073671" Qxy="-0.00014277" Qxz="0.00014533" Qyy="0.00039546" Qyz="-0.00000568" Qzz="0.00262066" MeanError="1.00000000" />
            </GPSPositionVelocity>
            <TiltInfo tilt="2.09289226" tiltQuality="0.20604831" maxTilt="2.09289172" maxTiltQuality="0.20604831" tiltDirection="292.82119353" tiltDirectionQuality="6.73585423" antennaHeading="126.49655262" antennaHeadingQuality="1.56022984">
               <AttitudeQuaternion w="0.545783971615954" x="0.014694157165700" y="-0.007365463010343" z="-0.837764697290921">
                  <QuaternionQuality Qxx="0.0000105379" Qxy="0.0000002941" Qxz="-0.0000101108" Qyy="0.0000108098" Qyz="0.0000066687" Qzz="0.0008271720" MeanError="63.6619772368" />
               </AttitudeQuaternion>
               <AngularVelocity velocityX="-3.1438191155" velocityY="1.5740678692" velocityZ="-1.4080006143" AngularVelocityType="angularUnitPerSecond">
                  <VelocityQuality Qxx="0.0000001490" Qxy="0.0000002552" Qxz="-0.0000000169" Qyy="0.0000005309" Qyz="0.0000000154" Qzz="0.0000003482" MeanError="63.6619772368" />
               </AngularVelocity>
               <LeverArm deltaNorth="0.001000" deltaEast="0.000280" deltaUp="-1.643910" />
            </TiltInfo>
         </GPSPosition>
      </GPSSetup>
   </Survey>
</root>
```

where the output comment `<!--tiltQuality: 0.20604831; verticalOffset: 0.000000-->` suggest the XPath expressions find data.

So please consider to provide minimal but complete samples to allow us to reproduce the problem, together with information as to which XSLT 1.0 processor you use.

Comment: I'll try to make the XML and the XSLT as short as possible.